# Using WCF client: "Use the XmlInclude or SoapInclude attribute to specify types that are not known statically."

Tags: c#, wcf, xml-serialization, ixmlserializable

I have to call a Web Service, that in the request, has a property like this:

```
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Criteria", typeof(QueryTypeCriteria), Order=2)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Identification", typeof(BaseComponentType), Order=2)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("SortExpression", typeof(SortExpressionType), Order=2)]
    public object[] Items {
        get {
            return this.itemsField;
        }
        set {
            this.itemsField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("Items");
        }
    }
```

After build the request, when I invoke the Web Service, I receive the following error:

> The type QueryTypeCriteria was not expected. Use the XmlInclude or
>   SoapInclude attribute to specify types that are not known statically.

I read that this is related to XmlSerializer, but this is a WCF client generated by Visual Studio. What can I do?

Comment: I don't understand, I assing Items to a value of type QueryTypeCriteria, but I get that error.